# Why are recursive sets also recursively enumerable?

Tags: computability

Why is this? I'm not necessarily interested in a full proof, but just a quick, simple explanation that makes sense as to why this is.

Comment: Which definitions of "recursive" and (in particular) "recursively enumerable" do you have to work from?

Comment: I'm using the following definitions: Recursive - algorithm decides if an input is in a set in a finite amount of time. Recursively enumerable - algorithm halts if element is in the set and does not if it isn't.

Comment: x @Ellen: With those (nice and sensible) definitions: If you have an algorithm that shows your set is recursive, you can make it into an algorithm that shows that the set is r.e. by replacing `print "yes"` with `halt` and `print "no"` with `loop forever`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, a set is **recursive** if there's a program that will take a number as input and then answer "yes" if the number is in the set and "no" if it isn't.

Similarly, a set is **recursively enumerable** if there's a program that will take a number as input and then answer "yes" if the number is in the set and *either answer "no" or keep running forever* if it isn't.

If you know that a set is recursive, thanks to some program, the very same program will also work for showing that it is recursively enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

Say $S$ is a recursive set of natural numbers. Given $n$, you have an algorithm to decide whether $n\in S$. So construct a list of the elements of $S$ like so: If $1\in S$ then add $1$ to the list, otherwise don't. If $2\in S$ add $2$ to the list, otherwise don't. Etc. You have enumerated the elements of $S$.